# Delimiter options with dlmwrite instruction in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have created 800 Poisson distributed random numbers. then write those numbers in a .txt file. I want to write my each data value in new line like,

```
1
2
3
```

but it is coming like

```
1 2 3..
```

I used `dlmwrite` as,

```
dlmwrite('rts2_data.txt',rts2, '\t');
```

Which delimiter should I use to take each data value in new line?

Comment: Are you sure this not just you editor that display tabulations as single space ? I've just tried opening `dlmwrite('toto.txt', [1 2 3 4], '\t')` with [`notepad++`](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and it works like a charm ... _(see ¶ button to visualize tabulations)_

Comment: Oops ... missunderstood ... use `\n` as delimiter to go to newline

Comment: or just use `save('data.txt','data','-ascii')`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know specifically about Matlab, but `\t` is the tabulation character.

If you want a new line, perhaps you could use the new line character, `\n`, or maybe `\r\n` if it does allow more than one character (`\r` is a "carriage return").

---

Ok, so Matlab doesn't allow to place the new line character directly as delimiter. Instead, you can use this syntax:

```
dlmwrite('rts2_data.txt', rts2, 'delimiter', ' ', 'newline', 'pc');
```

As seen [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/293335). You can also check out [this page](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/ref/dlmwrite.html) which documents the parameters available for the dlmwrite function.

Comment: if i use \r or \n, it give values like 1234..
if i use \r\n then matlab gives an error, '\r\n is not a valid attribute or delimiter.  Delimiter must be a single character.

Comment: In my Matlab version (R2012b)  `dlmwrite('rts2_data.txt',rts2, '\n')` does what is intended: it writes every number in a new line.

Answer (score 0):

You can arrange the data as a column vector initially (not a row). `dlmwrite` tries to keep a matrix structure you have.

Here is my working example:

```
z=[0 1 2 3]
dlmwrite('rts2_data1.txt',z)
dlmwrite('rts2_data2.txt',z')
```

and the outputs of the files are:

- rts2_data1.txt

  0,1,2,3
- rts2_data2.txt

  0

  1

  2

  3

Comment: i have made a column vector now but it is showing like ਲ਼਱ਲ਼ਲਲ਼਴਴ਲਲ਱਱ਲਲ਼..means not giving values